Should power steering hoses be replaced if there is no known problem?
My power steering system, which I know is closed must have a very slow leak somewhere. I was going to flush the system and I noticed the hose wasn't in good shape. I'm wondering whether or not these hoses should be replaced before failure? Or whether people just wait until failure to replace them.
I've never seen a hose with this kind of indentation under the clip. Is this normal and cause for concern?


The indentation is nothing to worry about. This is normal, especially with the spring clamp on there. This is a non-pressure line for power steering, so even less of an issue. If the hoses aren't cracking, nor leaking, don't worry about them. The non-pressure line as you've got there will probably last the lifetime of the vehicle without issue. If this was a pressure line with cracking or is leaking, definitely replace. The other thing about power steering lines is that even if they fail, you can still drive the car. It's just harder to steer when going slow. Which makes them even less of a worry.

Thanks a ton! Flushing it now with that line
